# Opencv package not found even after adding the correct PKG_CONFIG_PATH

Tags: opencv, pkg-config

```
yapch@ywc:~$ echo PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=
yapch@ywc:~$ echo PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
yapch@ywc:~$ export  PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
yapch@ywc:~$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
yapch@ywc:~$ echo PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
yapch@ywc:~$ cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
yapch@ywc:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig$ ls
IlmBase.pc     libavformat.pc  libdeflate.pc       libjpeg.pc  libpng16.pc       libtiff-4.pc  python-3.10-embed.pc  tbb.pc
OpenEXR.pc     libavutil.pc    libexif.pc          liblzma.pc  libraw1394.pc     libtirpc.pc   python-3.10.pc        zlib.pc
expat.pc       libcrypt.pc     libgphoto2.pc       libnsl.pc   libswresample.pc  libxcrypt.pc  python3-embed.pc
libavcodec.pc  libdc1394-2.pc  libgphoto2_port.pc  libpng.pc   libswscale.pc     opencv4.pc    python3.pc
yapch@ywc:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig$ cd ~
yapch@ywc:~$ cd yolo/darknet/
yapch@ywc:~/yolo/darknet$ make
nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52] -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda-12.3/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DOPENCV -DGPU" --compiler-options "-std=c++11" -c ./src/convolutional_kernels.cu -o obj/convolutional_kernels.o
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
```

I have tried multiple times and I am still not sure how to solve this. The path was correct but it was not detected still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pkg-config file is called `opencv4.pc` per your `ls` output so change your Makefile to say `pkg-config --cflags opencv4`.  If it is defined as a variable you may be able to override it on the command line.

Comment: If I answered your question please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it.